# IVY Unresolved dependencies GWT 2.7.0

Tags: gwt, ivy

I'm trying to resolve the following dependencies using IVY 2.5.0-rc1 where gwt.version=[2.7.0, 2.8.0, 2.8.2] and I'm pointing to https://jcenter.bintray.com/ as a repository

```
 <dependency org="com.google.gwt" name="gwt-user" rev="${gwt.version}" 
            conf="gwt-compile, compile->master"/>
<dependency org="com.google.gwt" name="gwt-dev" rev="${gwt.version}" 
        conf="compile, gwt-compile->master" />
<dependency org="com.google.gwt" name="gwt-servlet" rev="${gwt.version}" 
        conf="compile, gwt-compile, war-libs->master"  />
```

This results in the following output

```
[ivy:resolve] :: problems summary ::
[ivy:resolve] :::: WARNINGS
[ivy:resolve]       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:resolve]       ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[ivy:resolve]       ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[ivy:resolve]       :: com.google.gwt#gwt-user;2.7.0: com.google.gwt#gwt;2.7.0->org.sonatype.oss#oss-parent;4
[ivy:resolve]       :: com.google.gwt#gwt-dev;2.7.0: com.google.gwt#gwt;2.7.0->org.sonatype.oss#oss-parent;4
[ivy:resolve]       :: com.google.gwt#gwt-servlet;2.7.0: com.google.gwt#gwt;2.7.0->org.sonatype.oss#oss-parent;4
```

The org.sonatype.oss#oss-parent;4 appears to exist in the repository https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/sonatype/oss/oss-parent/
I've tried using excludes for oss-parent both at the dependency and dependencies level without success. I've also tried setting the transitive=false attribute on the gwt dependency elements.

The only relevant post I could find was [this](https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17122531), which has no response.

I also saw the following deprecation warning regarding [oss-parent](https://github.com/sonatype/oss-parents)

```
Sonatype OSS Parent poms - oss-parents
DEPRECATION WARNING:

This project is no longer active or supported. We suggest to manage parent POM files for your own organization as needed. The POM files from this project no longer work with latest Maven and/or Java versions.

For deployments to the Central Repository and the needed setup, please refer to http://central.sonatype.org
```

Comment: We have run into this as well.  I believe it is a bug in IVY dependency resolver and/or -> pom to ivy.xml conversion, but haven't been able to confirm through any real testing.  We use eclipse for development.  For eclipse we have a special configuration the excludes these dependencies and then on our CI server, we are actually using an older version of IVY.

You can try adding transitive="false" and adding other gwt dependencies directly, and/or adding particular <artifact> sub tags.

Comment: I ended up copying the artifacts minus the POM files to another repo on our artifactory instance. I couldn't find the combination of attributes on the dependency/resolver to avoid it trying to resolve the POM files.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the following bug in ivy 2.5.0-rc1: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IVY-1588

The best workaround I've found until they push out a release with the fix they implemented is to downgrade to ivy 2.4